Calculating the joint pdf of linearly dependent random variables $X$ and $Y=X$
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables and $p_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$ be the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$. Suppose that $(X,Y)$ transformed to $(X,X)$. We want to calculate the joint pdf of transformed random variables.
From this, we know that as we normally take $g(X,Y)=U$ and $h(X,Y)=V$. This gives us that, using the $g(X,Y)=X=h(X,Y)$, we get $U=V$. Also the corresponding Jacobian matrix can be given as
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
But this is non-invertible. I have problem in computing the joint pdf of the transformed random variables. I also see online and come to know that the joint pdf of $(X,X)$ is $p_{X}(x)\delta(x-y)$. Here I am not able to calculate the $\delta$ from the usual methods. Also I have calculated the first cdf as $P(X<x,Y<y)=P(X<x,X<y)=P(X<\min(x,y))$. From this cdf, can I calculate the desired pdf?

There is no joint pdf, because this is not a continuous distribution.

@whuber, anyhow can we write the pdf of (X,X) tranformed random variables?

That would be the pdf of $X.$

As already explained in comments, there is no joint density in the plane, because all the probability mass of $(X, X)$ is concentrated on the diagonal $y=x$. There is a density on that diagonal, but that is simply the density of $X$.
Maybe you would be better off asking the real problem where this occurs? All probabilities in this setting can be calculated from the density of $X$, so it is unclear what is your real problem!

We have to be a little careful with the meaning of "density on the diagonal," because it depends on how the diagonal is parameterized.  For instance, the density of $(X,X)$ relative to Lebesgue measure on the diagonal inherited from $\mathbb R^2$ is $\sqrt{1/2}$ times the density of $X.$
